# Where does Python search for modules after installing Anaconda?

Tags: python, unix, path

Previously, I have been using Python 2.7. If I installed a module using pip, it would place the module in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Then, if I were to `import` that module in a python script, the `site-packages` directory would be searched to find that module.

However, I want to start using the Anaconda distribution. After downloading this, I notice that there are a number of packages located at `/home/karnivaurus/Anaconda/pkgs`, for example `scikit-learn`. Then, in the directory of each packages, there is the directory structure `lib/python2.7/site-packages`, which contains the modules for that package.

So, it seems that I have now gone from the situation where I only had one `site-packages` directory, to where I have a number of `site-packages` directories, one for each package.

My question is: When I create a python script, and want to import a module, how does python know where to look for these modules? Will it look in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` as well as the `site-packages` directories that come with Anaconda? What if I want to install another package that does not come with Anaconda -- where should this be installed to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The paths in which Python will import packages can be seen with the following command:

```
python -c "import sys; print sys.path"
```

Please see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path), also (as stated in the documentation) if you need to modify the search path, look into [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).